# I am trying to create alerts when someone changes the IAM RBAC roles or permissions on azure storage accounts using Kusto query

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, kql, azure-monitoring

```bash
AzureActivity
| where ResourceProviderValue contains "Microsoft.storage" and CategoryValue contains "Administrative"
| where OperationNameValue ==
"Microsoft. Authorization/roleAssignments/write",
"Microsoft. Authorization/roleAssignments/delete",
"Microsoft. Authorization/roleDefinitions/write",
"Microsoft. Authorization/roleDefinitions/delete"
| where ActivityStatusValue in (""Started", "Succeeded", "Failed")
| project TimeGenerated, ResourceId, OperationNameValue, ActivityStatus
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing with the above query. @Sahith Thatipalli

Comment: What's the problem with your attempt?

Comment: I think I am missing the format for the format for the operation name value in the query. 
Moreover, I have tried to follow the step as mentioned but I cannot see any signal that is related to the RBAC role.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create alerts when someone changes the IAM RBAC roles or permissions on azure storage accounts using Kusto query.

Alternatively, you can create an alert from the portal when someone changes the **IAM RBAC** roles on a storage account, follow these steps.

1. Go to `Azure Storage account > Activity log > select any Create role assignment operation > New alert rule`

[image]

2. Select the `scope (ex: subscription) > Resource type : Storage accounts.`

[image]

3. Select the **Signal: Create a role assignment**

[image]

4. Create an action group using your **email ID** or choose an existing one.
5. To fetch all role assignment and deletion, select all in the status field of the condition tab.

[image]

7. After completing all the steps above, you will receive an alert if anyone changes the **RBAC** role on the storage account, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am actually looking for a Kusto query code in order to create the alert. The solution only defines create of role assignment. I am looking to include these log entries which also mentions Delete role assignment, Create or update role definition, Delete role definition.

Comment: Hi @SahithThatipalli,I will check and get back to you regarding your requirement.